# Можно ли запретить переопределение переменных/методов в php?

Tags: php, ооп

Можно ли запретить переопределение переменных/методов (например созданных в абстрактном классе) в php? И если да, каким образом это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
final public function example()
{
 // ...
}
```

Используйте [Ключевое слово final](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.final.php)

> Замечание: Свойства не могут быть объявлены окончательными, только
>   классы и методы.